# cPanel, redirection and aliases (forces redirection)

Tags: redirects, webserver

I have cPanel and I have domain A, Then I created a Domain Alias B,

But Alias B has been redirected to A domain, I don't want to redirect it.

Comment: Have you explicitly set up redirection in cPanel? What kind of site do you have ... CMS/WordPress? If you've not set up the domain redirection in cPanel then please include the contents of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Also a screenshot of the alias page so we can see the document_root

Answer (score 0):

The [cPanel documentation about aliases](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Aliases) says that redirection can be either enabled or disabled:

> #### Enable or disable domain alias redirection
>
> To enable or disable redirection of a domain alias, perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Click *Manage Redirection* for the domain alias that you wish to manage.
> 2. To redirect the domain, enter the link to which you wish to redirect the domain alias in the text box.
> 3. Click Save. To disable the redirection, click *Disable Redirection*.

Comment: I disabled redirection of my alias, But it still redirected.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your .htaccess file as requested by MrWhite then.